# How to provide CdvPurchase.Store in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, cordova-plugin-purchase

How can I setup [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) v13 with Angular 15?

This is what I have tried. Here is my PaymentService which is provided in root.

```
// payment.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import 'cordova-plugin-purchase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentService {

  constructor(
    private readonly store: CdvPurchase.Store,
    private readonly platform: Platform,
  ) {

    this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
      this.store.initialize();
    });
  }
}
```

I'm providing the Store class in AppModule

```
// app.module.ts
import 'cordova-plugin-purchase';

@NgModule({
    // Omitting unrelevant parts
    providers: [
        {
            provide: CdvPurchase.Store,
            useFactory: () => { return window.CdvPurchase.Store }
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Firstly I'm getting this error in app.module.ts

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CdvPurchase is not defined
```

And down the line I'm getting this dependency injection error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(PaymentModule)[PaymentService -> PaymentService -> Store -> Store -> Store]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(PaymentModule)[PaymentService -> PaymentService -> Store -> Store -> Store]:
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where you able to get this working? I'm having same issue upgrading to v13.

Comment: Have the same problem. The only way to import cordova-plugin-purchase/www/store.js, but I don't know if it is correct way

Answer (score 0):

@Component({
selector: 'app-questions',
templateUrl: './napp2.page.html' ,
providers: [{provide: CdvPurchase.Store}]

})

its work for me

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer